# Запятая перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Новый айфон будет (выглядеть) как телефон справа.

Ставится ли здесь запятая?

В правилах есть такие примеры:

*Ставится*

**Запятая перед как ставится в том случае, если этот союз начинает сравнительный оборот. Например, вода в озере блестела, как зеркало. В данном случае вода как будто зеркало, а как является началом сравнительного оборота, поэтому перед союзом нужно поставить запятую.**

*Не ставится*

**Если союз как является частью сказуемого. В таком случае без как предложение также теряет смысл. Она вела себя как настоящая хозяйка. Понятно, что без как или без как настоящая хозяйка, предложение просто теряет смысл.**

А в чем разница? Во втором примере: Она как будто хозяйка. Аналогично с первым.

Я запутался. Когда сравнение, а когда нет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно: Новый айфон будет как телефон справа. Сравнительный оборот в роли сказуемого.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Важно понять следующее: сравнительный оборот не имеет особых правил обособления, отличных от общих правил, но проявляет большую самостоятельность по сравнению с другими членами предложения. Если он является или входит в состав сказуемого, то его нельзя обособить (главный член не обособляется). Поэтому мы не можем ориентироваться только на семантику оборота. Один и тот же оборот может обособляться или не обособляться в зависимости от своей роли в разных предложениях.

2) Обособление сравнительного оборота зависит от его синтаксической роли и от грамматической структуры предложения. В большинстве случаев сравнительный оборот ОБОСОБЛЯЕТСЯ.  Но сравнительный оборот НЕ ОБОСОБЛЯЕТСЯ, если является сказуемым  или  обстоятельством в основном сообщении.

3) О сказуемом. Оборот с союзом КАК не обособляется, если он является сказуемым в основном сообщении, входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу. В  этом случае сказуемое без сравнительного оборота не имеет законченного выражения.

Сказуемое: Весёлая песня как крылатая птица. Всё это и теперь для меня как мираж.

В составе сказуемого, полузнаменательная или знаменательная связка:
Лес стоял как сплошная стена. Как ребёнок душою я стал.

Тесная связь со сказуемым: В баснях звери ведут себя как люди. Она держится как хозяйка.

Answer (score 4):

> > А в чем разница? Во втором примере: Она как будто хозяйка. Аналогично с первым.

Вы не изменяйте предложение-то.
 1. "Вода в озере блестела". Смысл не изменился.
 2. "Она вела себя". Смысла нет, предложение не закончено.

Вот в этом и разница.

В примере Софии:

"Лес стоял как сплошная стена" – Лес стоял. Вроде бы смысл не потерян, но он изменился! Говорится же, что лес стоял стеной, а не просто стоял? Поэтому "как стена" – часть сказуемого.