# "Я стал как лев"

Tags: пунктуация

Запятая перед "как" не нужна? Почему (и в том случае, если нужна)?

Comment: http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужна. Потому что "стал как лев" - сказуемое в этом простом предложении.

А когда нужна?

*Я стал, как разъярённый лев, сражаться за эту запятую.* Можно и без разъярённости.

То есть при сравнении.

Это не то же, что *как демон коварна и зла* = демонически коварна.

Подробно: [**тут**](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/317-zapyatayaperedsyuzomkak.html), [**тут**](http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/1946d260-e1a1-4308-8126-72b39aaea09a/punc17.htm) и [**тут**](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=265): обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) *как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что*.

---

Похожий вопрос на этом сайте - ***[Запятая перед “как”](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/38717/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA)***.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! Улыбнул пример.)))