# Запятые перед "как лошадь", "как собака"

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

Вчера в некой книге увидел следующее предложение.

***Он работал, как лошадь, и уставал, как собака.***

Я, признаться, не поставил бы здесь никаких запятых. Разве "работать как лошадь" и "уставать как собака" это не фразеологизмы? Подскажите, какое правило пунктуации применимо в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

Вы совершенно правы. Запятые не нужны.

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос: ["Я стал как лев"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420309/%D0%AF-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2).

Действительно, *"работал как лошадь"* и *"уставал как собака"* у Вас сказуемые, которые нельзя разбивать на части. Они как единое целое.

Comment: Так что ж это получается? Довольно известный писатель, на счету которого уже с десяток книг, пишет предложение с довольно примитивной ошибкой? И редакторы, вычитывающие текст перед сдачей книги в тираж, тоже это пропускают? Странно как-то...

Comment: Да, странно, но если это современная книжка, это не так удивительно, к сожалению. Это раньше, в советское время, книги выходили практически без ошибок. А писатель должен в первую очередь писать интересно, полезно; хорошо, если он ещё и высокограмотный, но это не необходимо во что бы то ни стало.

Comment: @Vol,  Ну, то что автор написал десяток книг, ни о чем не говорит. Это работа корректора. А они - ребята с норовом, попался вот такой упрямец, который не видит фразеологизма в данном конретном случае - и ничего не докажешь. А может как раз автор настоял, что он не имеет в виду фразеологизм, у него личное понимание это работы. Вот один автор как отмочил про раба на галерах, так сразу фразеологизмом и стало.